# CSS: Float inline-blocks around single block element on more than one line

Tags: css, css-float

[image: screenshot]

What I need is to float both red elements on the side of the green one, stacked directly one above the other, in such a manner that the outer block will respect the total width of green + longest red.

Output needed:

[image]

Here is the fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/r71bapbn/1/**

So far HTML:

```
<div>
    <label>
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <span class="text1">Some text</span><br />
        <span class="text2">Some other text</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    display:inline-block;
}
label {
    display:inline-block;
    background:rgba(230, 230, 255, 1);
    padding:10px;
}
span {
    display:inline-block;
    background:rgba(255, 200, 200, 1);
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.icon {
    display:block;
    width:40px;
    height:50px;
    background:rgba(200, 255, 200, 1);
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: what output you need? can you please show the image?

Comment: Like this? - http://jsfiddle.net/r71bapbn/3/

Comment: Do you want this ? http://jsfiddle.net/r71bapbn/4/

Comment: Added needed output image...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Remove `<br>`
- Add `overflow: auto`
- Remove `white-space: nowrap`
- Add to `.text1` and `.text2` a `margin-left` of the `.icon`'s width

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <label>
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <span class="text1">Some text</span>
        <span class="text2">Some other text</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    background:rgba(230, 230, 255, 1);
    padding:10px;
    overflow: auto;
}
span {
    display:block;
    background:rgba(255, 200, 200, 1);
}
.icon {
    display:block;
    width:40px;
    height:50px;
    background:rgba(200, 255, 200, 1);
    float:left;
}
.text1, .text2 {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Fiddle forked here : http://jsfiddle.net/f5h5vx06/

Comment: Acceptable approach! Just one question, why `overflow:auto` on `label`? It seems to work without it...

Comment: Just a habit I have when I float something: I `overflow` the parent. Could be useless, indeed, but doesn't really disturb

Comment: I've been testing all these solutions and went for the one that C-link Nepal's suggested due to better code centralization. Nevertheless, your solution deserves credits due to pure CSS approach. I am sure there are developers who will need exactly this. Upvoted!

Comment: `overflow:auto` is not just your habit as I just discovered! Try to remove overflow here http://jsfiddle.net/7520ztfz/1/ and the parent element won't respect the height of the floated element. It's necessary if the parent is a block!

Comment: exact! I didn't mention it's a habit I have to **clear the floats**, my bad! you **need** it if you float something and don't want to use the usual `clear: both` rule

Answer (score 1):

Remove the inline-block from the span and add width to label:

```
div {
    display:inline-block;
}
label {
    display:inline-block;
    background:rgba(230, 230, 255, 1);
    padding:10px;
    width: 140px;
}
span {
    background:rgba(255, 200, 200, 1);
}
.icon {
    display:block;
    width:40px;
    height:50px;
    background:rgba(200, 255, 200, 1);
    float:left;
}
.text1 {

}
.text2 {

}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r71bapbn/5/)

---

**Updated:**

Normally we group the elements which we have to float like below html:

```
<div>
    <label>
        <span class="icon"></span><!--this would be floated-->
        <spa class="group"><!--this would be floated-->
        <span class="text1">Some text</span><br />
        <span class="text2">Some other text</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</div>
```

And here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r71bapbn/16/)

But be sure to clear the floats like using `overflow:hidden` to parent element i.e. label.

Comment: Thanks, but the total width of the outer element is dynamic, depending on the inner content. Can't just set fixed width in `px`.

Comment: Yes I can change HTML. But I would like to do the line break in CSS because I have two modes, normal (stacked above each other) and compact (stacked horzontally to save vertical space)

Comment: It seems like a very much suitable approach (link in the comment), I will need to test how it behaves, since it introduces `float` for other elements. I will reflect here soon.

Comment: I've been playing around with your approach. The only thing that actually needs to change to get from where I was to where desired situation is wrapping red ones with one parent element. Works like a charm and without any side effects. Also no need to float the `group` to the right. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/r71bapbn/20/

Comment: Yes, it no needs to use float, but what are you trying to say me? Any problem?

Comment: I'm trying to say it's a good technique. Right what I need. I am implementing this right now. Thank you. Would be nice if you've updated your answer to be more simple for others.

Comment: I've already updated, not? Should I remove previous one? And modify with more details?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61001/discussion-between-alph-dev-and-c-link-nepal).

Answer (score 1):

I Hope this Code will Help You.

Here is Your [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/r71bapbn/15/)

**CSS**

```
div {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
label {
    display:inline-block;
    background:rgba(230, 230, 255, 1);
    padding:10px;
    width: 140px;
}
span {
    display:flex;
    background:rgba(255, 200, 200, 1);
    white-space:nowrap;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.icon {
    display:block;
    width:40px;
    height:50px;
    background:rgba(200, 255, 200, 1);
    float:left;
}
.text1 {
width: 65px;    
}
.text2 {

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <label><div>
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <span class="text1">Some text</span>
        <span class="text2">Some other text</span></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: @C-linkNepal: can you please look at the code , I dont want to copy others code, just i tried and updated.

Comment: @C-linkNepal :If i get the actual output I can just update it, Here there is nothing which i copied.

Comment: @KesaVan Thanks for the input. I will need to do some research on the side effects and browser support of `display:flex`. Also if it will work without setting fixed width to `.text1`. Red elements contain dynamic amount of text (multi-language dynamic content). Also if the same solution is presented I'll accept the earlier one, and if there is a slight difference, upvote both for others with the same problem to pick. Thanks for your contributions! I need some time to process all these beautiful solutions ;)

Comment: @Alph.Dev : Ok Sure, Thanks, If you have any doubt let me know.

Comment: @KesaVan: Thanks for a future-oriented approach! It allows to achieve the result by basically a single CSS line. Due to browser compatibility (mostly IE ofcourse, thanks MS), for now I'm going with wrapping reds in a parent element. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

Set the icon width to a percentage, then also set the text to a percentage (adding upto 100% of course). And remove the line break. Fiddle Below

http://jsfiddle.net/q35wffht/

html;

```
<div>
    <div class="left">
        <span class="icon"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <span class="text1">Some text</span><br/>
        <span class="text2">Some other text</span>
    </div>
```

css;

```
    div {
    display:inline-block;
}
.left {
    width: 40px;
    float: left;
}
.right {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
}
span {
    display:inline-block;
    background:rgba(255, 200, 200, 1);
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.icon {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:rgba(200, 255, 200, 1);
    float:left;
}
.text1 {
float: left;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
.text2 {
   float: left;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Setting the icon width to a percentage is not acceptable in this case. `.icon` is a fixed size image and the text elements contain dynamic amount of text (different content).

Comment: I have updated my code, and fiddle, this should work as you need?

Answer (score 0):

### Alternative to float

I've encountered a lot of problems using `float` because it takes floated element out of the normal document flow. Thanks to the ideas provided in other answers here, I've managed to create this layout in the alternative way, without floating elements.

**HTML** (note how span tags are placed directly to each other on purpose):

```
<div>
    <label>
        <span class="icon"></span><span class="group">
            <span class="text1">Some text</span><span class="text2">Some other text</span>
        </span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span class="icon"></span><span class="group">
            <span class="text1">Some longer text</span><span class="text2">Some other longer text</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div {
    display:inline-block;
}
label {
    display:block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    background:rgba(230, 230, 255, 1);
    padding:10px;
}
.icon {
    vertical-align:top;
    display: inline-block;
    width:40px;
    height:50px;
    background:rgba(200, 255, 200, 1);
}
.group{
    border:1px solid red;
}
.icon, .group{
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;    
}
.text1, .text2 {
   background:rgba(255, 200, 200, 1);
   display:block;
}
```

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/r71bapbn/21/

I recommend this technique if you want the parent element to properly respect the size of child elements.

Good luck!